# Embendding Python 3.4 into MacOS app

Tags: macos, python-3.x, static-libraries

I'm trying to get a Python 3.4 interpreter into my app without to distribute python framework.
I'm linking with the libpython3.4.a (which appear to have dependency on Python.framework/versions/3.4/Python), but as guessed, it need python framework.

Does someone experienced this issue ?

Logically,i should be able to link statically (real static) and just distribute the python34.zip modules, right ?

Thanks for you help.

EDIT:

Finally i downloaded the Python 3.4 sources and build a static version.
Now i don't have dependency issue.
So i include the python3.4.zip near my executable.
But now, when starting the application i have this error:
"Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec"

So, i set Py_SetProgramName() to my binary and Py_SetPath(zippath) before the Py_Initialize().

But i still have the "ImportError: No module named 'encodings'" issue.
I also have tested with a simple folder instead of a zip.

Comment: That isn't a system-default framework is it? I thought the system-default version was 2.7.  I have done this before, but not with 3.4.

Comment: Hi, Macosx use Python2.7. I just need to have python3 in my app. This is why i'm embedding it.

Comment: Well you can certainly do it.